# How to use history info/keep count?

Tags: command-history

`man history`  says `history info ?count?` and `history keep ?count?`. I don't know what the two question marks mean. I have tried `history keep 1000` to keep 1000 history items, but it just returned `fc: event not found: keep`. I could not find any examples of it from Google. How to use them. What are the question marks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manpage you are encountering most likely refers to the `history` command for the Tcl programming language. You probably want the `history` command for your shell. For Bash, you can get information for the command using `help history` or `man bash` (section `HISTORY`).

To keep a history of 1000 items in Bash, add this to your `.bashrc`: `HISTSIZE=1000`

Source the file to reflect the changes: `source ~/.bashrc`

Verify changes: `echo $HISTSIZE`